# Files created on server appear read only

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, file-permissions, cygwin

When I create a file on a windows server with cygwin the resulting file appears to be read-only. For example
    echo > hallo.txt

results in a file with these rights:

```
Path              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\rh-data-s01\Abteilungen\Neue Medien\hallo.txt
FileSystemRights  : WriteExtendedAttributes, ExecuteFile, DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, ReadPermissions
AccessControlType : Deny
IdentityReference : NULL SID
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None

Path              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\rh-data-s01\Abteilungen\Neue Medien\hallo.txt
FileSystemRights  : Write, Delete, Read, ChangePermissions, TakeOwnership, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : S-1-15-3-1024-1065365936-1281604716-3511738428-1654721687-432734479-3232135806-4053264122-3456934681
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None

Path              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\rh-data-s01\Abteilungen\Neue Medien\hallo.txt
FileSystemRights  : ExecuteFile
AccessControlType : Deny
IdentityReference : S-1-5-32-4028125388-2803578072-1053907958-341417128-2434011155-477421480-740873757-3973419746
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None

Path              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\rh-data-s01\Abteilungen\Neue Medien\hallo.txt
FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : S-1-5-32-4028125388-2803578072-1053907958-341417128-2434011155-477421480-740873757-3973419746
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None

Path              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\rh-data-s01\Abteilungen\Neue Medien\hallo.txt
FileSystemRights  : Read, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : Everyone
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None
```

On this file Windows suggest to "reorder" file permissions. I went through the posix permissions page but could not find a solution.

How do I create a file that can be access later on without having to fiddle with access rights?

Answer (score 1):

By default, cygwin tries to match the NTFS ACLs to POSIX permissions.

From the [docs](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-filemodes.html):

> On NTFS, file permissions are evaluated using the Access Control Lists
>   (ACLs) attached to a file. This can be switched off by using the
>   "noacl" option to the respective mount point in the /etc/fstab or
>   /etc/fstab.d/$USER file. For more information on file permissions, see
>   the section called “POSIX accounts, permission, and security”.

So use `noacl` to mount or [map your Windows / NTFS to POSIX accounts](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html):

> Cygwin's mapping between SIDs and uid/gid values works in two ways.
>
> Read /etc/passwd and /etc/group files if they exist, just as in the
>   olden days, mainly for backward compatibility.
>
> If no files are present, or if an entry is missing in the files, ask
>   Windows.
>
> At least, that's the default behaviour now. It will be configurable
>   using a file /etc/nsswitch.conf, which is discussed in the section
>   called “The /etc/nsswitch.conf file”. Let's explore the default for
>   now.
>
> If the passwd or group files are present, they will be scanned on
>   demand as soon as a mapping from SIDs to uid/gid or account names is
>   required. The new mechanism will never read the entire file into
>   memory, but only scan for the requested entry and cache this one in
>   memory.
>
> If no entry is found, or no passwd or group file was present, Cygwin
>   will ask the OS.

This can also be done with SMB or NFS accounts. So just pick your poison.